# Htaccess rewrite rule - how to do (.*) but NOT if it is a certain word?

Tags: .htaccess, unix, mod-rewrite

I have this run in my .htaccess:

> `RewriteRule ^(.*)/videos/(.*) vid.php?a=$1&b=$2 [NC,L]`

which works fine, except i have this folder:
/images/videos/
which have images in.

How can i modify that RewriteRule so it catches everything in the first (.*) EXCEPT 'images'?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out

```
RewriteRule ^(?!images)(.*)/videos/(.*)/ vid.php?a=$1
```

the ?!images is the negative lookahead thing.